# How to animate the new annotation in iOS 17 in MapKit based on a change in location?

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit, ios17

In MK this was strait forward, but I can't seem to find anything that works with the new MapKit.

Requirement:  When location changes, animate smoothly the annotation from `oldValue` to `newValue`.

So I have tried almost everything, but eventually landed on the notion of fractionalizing the delta between `oldValue` and `newValue` by 100, then brute force updating the position for each fraction.  Here is the function I am working with:

```
func animateAnnotationMove(from oldCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, steps: Int = 100, interval: TimeInterval = 0.05) {
    let latitudeDiff = (newCoordinate.latitude - oldCoordinate.latitude) / Double(steps)
    let longitudeDiff = (newCoordinate.longitude - oldCoordinate.longitude) / Double(steps)
    
    var currentStep = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard currentStep < steps else {
            timer.invalidate() // Stop the timer
            return
        }
        
        let nextLatitude = oldCoordinate.latitude + (latitudeDiff * Double(currentStep))
        let nextLongitude = oldCoordinate.longitude + (longitudeDiff * Double(currentStep))
        let nextCoordinate = CLLocaionCoordinate2D(latitude: nextLatitude, longitude: nextLongitude)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.updateGuestAnnotationPosition(with: nextCoordinate)
        }
        
        currentStep += 1
    }
}
```

My concern is that this is not very efficient as I scale, and with SwiftUI's ability to just animate in many other areas, maybe I'm missing something obvious?  My location data updates every 5 seconds, so the thinking here is to break that down into 100 function calls (so every 0.05 seconds) and animate the delta.

Comment: Can you share more of the code? Maybe a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? By the way, I don't think a timer is a good idea, they are energy hungry and CPU intensive. Have you tried updating the coordinate using `withAnimation`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got my custom annotation to animate including the Map keeping the annotation in the center.

```
@State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)))

var body: some View {
        
        @State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: plane.lat ?? 0, longitude: plane.lon ?? 0)
        
        @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.3, longitudeDelta: 0.3))
        
        Map(
            position: $cameraPosition,
            //initialPosition: .region(region)
            interactionModes: [.pan, .zoom]
        ) {
            
            Annotation(coordinate: location) {
                
                Image(systemName: "airplane")
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: (plane.track ?? 0) + -90))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5), value: plane.track)
                
            } label: {
                Label {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(plane.desc ?? "")
                    }
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane")
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: plane.lon) {
            withAnimation(.smooth(duration:  3.5)) {
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: plane.lat ??  0, longitude: plane.lon ??  0)
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:  0.3, longitudeDelta:  0.3))
                cameraPosition = .region(region)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: location)
        .mapControlVisibility(.visible)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```